# Is there any way in Phoenix generate only controller, without a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elixir, phoenix-framework

Is there any way in Phoenix generate only controller, without a model? In rails I'd do that by

```
rails g controller Home index about
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per version 1.2, nope there is no direct mix task for it yet. Checked in the docs https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.html

Though you could use another way as stated by @michalmuskala use

`mix phoenix.gen.html --no-model`

Comment: In 1.6+ this would now be `mix phx.gen.html --no-schema` as documented here: https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Mix.Tasks.Phx.Gen.Html.html#module-customizing-the-context-schema-tables-and-migrations

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `--no-model` option to `mix phoenix.gen.json/html` to skip models and migrations, effectively getting just the controller.

Comment: Note that this will generate all the CRUD actions in the controller (and tests for them), unlike the `rails g` command posted by OP.